# Reputation icon keeps showing +5

Tags: discussion, reputation

About an hour ago I asked [a question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/is-my-question-on-topic-for-mse) on Meta, and somebody recently upvoted it.  Around the same time, somebody upvoted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858806/infinite-tetration-of-2-5) on the main site.

Something very weird is happening.  To be clear, this does not occur on the main site; it only happens on [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/is-my-question-on-topic-for-mse) specific post.  The reputation button at the top of the page keeps showing +5.  If I click the button and then click outside the list of events the +5 goes away.  But if I reload the page the +5 reappears.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @AsafKaragila Please explain in plain English

Comment: @AsafKaragila Are you trying to tell me to try clearing my browser cache, or was it just a joke?

Comment: Well, I deleted my entire browsing history and the problem is now solved.

Comment: In the future: hold Shift and click on Refresh/Reload in your browser.

Comment: @J.M.: You mean Control.

Comment: No @Asaf, [I meant Shift](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3630). ;)

Comment: @J.M.: That's the wrong key if you're using Firefox. You don't want to shift your refresh. You want to *control* it.